# ValueError when parsing html (beatifulsoup)

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a table from wikipedia
When using `pd.read_html` but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 data-sort-value='
```

As far as I understand I can't just change occurences of '1 data-sort-value' without changing the layout of the table.

Here is the code

```
wikiurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_events'
response=requests.get(wikiurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table= soup.find('table', id="Past_events")

df=pd.read_html(str(table))
```

Comment: The problem is the table is buggy. `rowspan="1 data-sort-value="` is not a valid value for rowspan. You have to fix the html before use `read_html` :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually not parsing the table with BeautifulSoup. You are parsing with pandas (which uses BeautifulSoup under the hood). If you are using pandas to parse the table, there is no need to include bs4 here, you'd simply do:

```
wikiurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_events'
df=pd.read_html(wikiurl, attrs={'id':'Past_events'})
```

That being said, the structure of this table as stated in the comments by Corralien is buggy/not straight forward in that the attribute `rowspan` has an added `data-sort-value` that is not accounted for in pandas. So we do need to use BeautifulSoup to do the task of either removing the attribute (since it is a span of 1) or just removing the `data-sort-value` part and leave `'1'`.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


wikiurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_events'
response=requests.get(wikiurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', id="Past_events")

tds = table.find_all('td')
for td in tds:
    if 'rowspan' in td.attrs:
        if 'data-sort-value' in td.attrs['rowspan']:
            td.attrs['rowspan'] = '1'

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
[       #                                Event  ... Attendance   Ref.
0    581     UFC Fight Night: Ladd vs. Dumont  ...        NaN   [21]
1    580  UFC Fight Night: Dern vs. Rodriguez  ...        NaN   [22]
2    579   UFC Fight Night: Santos vs. Walker  ...        NaN   [23]
3    578      UFC 266: Volkanovski vs. Ortega  ...      19029   [24]
4    577     UFC Fight Night: Smith vs. Spann  ...        NaN   [25]
..   ...                                  ...  ...        ...    ...
585  005       UFC 5: The Return of the Beast  ...       6000  [543]
586  004       UFC 4: Revenge of the Warriors  ...       5857  [544]
587  003            UFC 3: The American Dream  ...        NaN    NaN
588  002                    UFC 2: No Way Out  ...       2000  [545]
589  001                 UFC 1: The Beginning  ...       7800  [546]

[590 rows x 7 columns]]
```